# Advantages of populating select tags with objects instead of string values

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I am developing a web application where in I have a form with some select tags which should be populated based on the selected value on a preceding select tag. The application is build using ***Struts2 and Hibernate***. Now my question is is it necessary for me to populate the select tags with objects or populating them with string values provides **better performance**.
[image]

Here I have populated *Select Company* with objects of type **Company** from database and *onselect* the values of the *Select Item* gets updated similarly using objects of type **Item**. So in this instance I had to use **hibernate query** to populate the tags. Since the Select Company tag **can also be populated by just retrieving only the company name from the company table** and similarly for Item tag using SQL query. was it worth using hibernate over sql. There must be some advantages of populating tags using objects and if some one can explain them it would be helpful.

Comment: It is unclear how did you measure a performance, could you provide details?

Comment: The question is very unclear...

Comment: @RomanC I have tried to explain my question clearly.have a look now.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Have a look do I make sense now?

Comment: @RomanC I didn't mean to say better performance in terms of a parameter what I meant to ask was in general

Comment: If you use parameter in the query it would be  better performance.

Comment: If you need objects then populate with objects, otherwise use strings.

Answer (score 0):

Definitively, sending only the data you need to the front end will save bandwith, and save time during the serialization.

Using AJAX to send data to the frontend when it is needed instead of loading everything at the first round will also save CPU and bandwith.

By the way, if you could provide us more information we might help you to get a well designed system.